# MySQL fetch Punch in and punch out data of employee

Tags: mysql

I am trying to run query to fetch data of employees punch in and punch out month wise. Problem is both punch ( in and out) are in same column.
I have two tables 'employee' and 'punch_time' as below

Table of Employee:

| Id | employee name |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | emp1 |
| 2 | emp2 |
| 3 | emp3 |

Table of Punch_time:

| PunchId | empId | punchTime |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | emp1 | 2022-05-01 10:02:25 |
| 2 | emp2 | 2022-05-01 10:00:23 |
| 3 | emp3 | 2022-05-01 18:15:04 |
| 4 | emp1 | 2022-05-01 18:10:25 |
| 5 | emp2 | 2022-05-01 18:00:00 |
| 6 | emp1 | 2022-05-02 10:00:05 |
| 7 | emp2 | 2022-05-02 10:10:15 |
| 8 | emp1 | 2022-05-02 18:02:25 |
| 9 | emp2 | 2022-05-02 18:02:25 |

I need result as below:

| emp. | Date | In. | Out. |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| emp1 | 2022-05-01 | 10:02:25 | 18:10:25 |
| emp2 | 2022-05-01 | 10:23:00 | 18:00:00 |
| emp3 | 2022-05-01 | 18:15:04 |  |
| emp1 | 2022-05-02 | 10:00:05 | 18:02:25 |
| emp2 | 2022-05-02 | 10:10:15 | 18:02:25 |
| emp3 | 2022-05-02 |  |  |
| emp1 | 2022-05-03 |  |  |
| emp2 | 2022-05-03 |  |  |
| emp3 | 2022-05-03 |  |  |

Comment: can you show us at least what you did?

Comment: so what is your actual problem? does your existing query have an error or produce incorrect results? Please include your current query, even if it's not fully working. You're basically after a simple *pivot*

Comment: It would likely be a good idea to record "in" or "out" against each punch time in the source table, I would have thought. P.s. have you researched this? You cannot be the first person to have this requirement

Comment: What if there is more than two records for the same employee on the same day?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an approach to get your desired records. The only thing missing is it doesn't show a line for absenteeism.

```
SELECT
    e.employeeName emp,
    CAST(punchTime AS DATE) punchDate,
    TIME(min(punchTime)) InTime,
    if(max(punchTime)=min(punchTime),null,TIME(max(punchTime))) OutTime
FROM Employee e
JOIN Punch_time p ON e.employeeName = p.empId
GROUP BY punchDate, empId;
```

[FIDDLE LINK](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/ae3f8HejZuDhJGfGCkJBi7/0)

Also, Advise to use EmpID (numerical index) in your PunchTime table. Currently the relationship is on a text field. Employee.employeeName <> Punch_Time.empId `NOT ADVISED`

Comment: its very helpful to me, but what if i want records with absenteeism

Comment: Post a new question please with sql tag

Answer (score -1):

Below is my approach, Change the tables and columns according to you schema

```
select EmpId,
   [Punch-In],
   [Punch-Out],
   DATEDIFF(SECOND, [Punch-In], [Punch-Out]) AS INTIME
```

from
(
select EmpId,
[Punch-In],
Lead([Punch-Out]) OVER (ORDER BY EMPID) AS [Punch-Out]
FROM
(
SELECT EmpId,
[Punch-In],
[Punch-Out]
FROM
(
SELECT CASE
WHEN LEN(pin) = 1 then
'00' + pin
WHEN LEN(pin) = 2 then
'0' + pin
else
pin
end AS EmpId,
Name as EmpName,
event_time as PunchTime,
CASE
WHEN reader_name LIKE '%-%in%' THEN
'Punch-In'
ELSE
'Punch-Out'
END AS PunchType,
id AS TransactionId,
datename(dw, event_time) as Day
FROM [acc_transaction] WITH (NOLOCK)
WHERE format(event_time, 'yyyy-MM-dd') = '2024-01-04'
and pin = '3573'
AND ISNULL(pin, '') <> ''
AND NULLIF(PIN, '') IS NOT NULL
AND pin NOT LIKE '%hk%'
AND name NOT LIKE '%temp%'
AND name NOT LIKE '%security%'
AND pin NOT LIKE 's%'
AND pin NOT LIKE 't%'
AND pin NOT LIKE 'c%'
AND name NOT LIKE 'test%'
AND event_no NOT IN ( 27, 23 )
AND event_point_name NOT IN ( '3A_Server_Room', 'CWF Z2 Server Room', 'CWF Z2 to Z3',
'3F Server Room', 'CWF Z3 to Z4', 'CWF Z3 Hub Room', 'CWFZ2 - 2-1',
'CWFZ2 - 2-2', 'Mys Server Room'
)
--order by event_time asc
) AS SourceTable
PIVOT
(
MIN(PunchTime)
FOR PunchType in ([Punch-In], [Punch-Out])
) AS PIVOTTABLE
) B
) c
where (
[Punch-In] is not null
or [Punch-Out] is not null
)

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).